# A mysterious email from Ryanair

Tags: cipher

You are a secret agent in the service of the KGB, and after a [setback](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/11088/a-mysterious-email-from-andrew-void) when the higher-ups thought your cover had been blown, you have embarked on a highly dangerous mission to infiltrate MI6. Under the pseudonym of Flynn Smith, you are working undercover in London when you receive the following mysterious email.

> From: "itinerary@ryanair.com" < itinerary@ryanair.com >
>   Sent: Wed, 13 May 2015 10:27AM +0400
>   To: ██████████████████████
>   Subject: Ryanair Travel Itinerary
>
> Dear Mr Smith,
>
> THANK YOU FOR BOOKING WITH RYANAIR.
>   THIS IS YOUR BOOKING CONFIRMATION, PASSENGER ITINERARY AND RECEIPT EMAIL. PLEASE CHECK YOUR FLIGHT(S) AND PASSENGER(S) DETAILS BELOW.
>
> **MSYSTLMSPORDSTLTPA RYGMUCZAGBUDHEM ADADMEIKAUFA KBLTSEKTMURC XNNDACRGNLPFXNN CGKPERDRWADLBNE**
>
> DO NOT REPLY TO THIS EMAIL.
>   <sub>Copyright 2014 Ryanair Ltd. All rights reserved. Cheap Flights - Lowest European Fares, Low Cost Airline.</sub>

You are confused: with all your expenses paid by the intelligence service, you never fly with a budget airline company like Ryanair. Perhaps they've got you mixed up with another Mr Smith - but how come your email address is on their records? Also there aren't even any ticket details in the email, only a nonsensical string of letters. The message must have been garbled.

But remembering your [previous experience](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/11088/a-mysterious-email-from-andrew-void) of an apparently spam email, you examine it more closely, wondering if there's a message hidden within it. After several minutes at your computer, you find the hidden message and your eyes widen. You reach for the drawer in which your handgun is stowed; you're in danger!

Looking even more closely, you realise that there's a second message hidden within the more obvious one. Your KGB agent handler is telling you where you must go - *and* probably also that you're in danger. It seems as though everything's under control, but you must move fast.

**What is the hidden message?**

Comment: I'd make a terrible spy

Comment: I don't work well under pressure :P

Comment: Beautiful puzzle.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Excellent puzzle! The secret message is

> RUN NOW

Here's how I solved it...

> Since the email seems to refer to a flight itinerary, I discovered that the code words must actually consist of three-letter airport abbreviations:
>  MSY = New Orleans, Louisiana
>  STL = St. Louis, Missouri
>  MSP = Minneapolis-Saint Paul, Minnesota
>  ORD = Chicago, Illinois
>  STL = St. Louis, Missouri
>  TPA = Tampa, Florida
>  RYG = Rygge, Norway
>  MUC = Munich, Germany
>  ZAG = Zagreb, Croatia
>  BUD = Budapest, Hungary
>  HEM = Helsinki, Finland
>  ADA = Adana, Turkey
>  DME = Moscow, Russia
>  IKA = Tehran, Iran
>  UFA = Ufa, Bashkortostan, Russia
>  KBL = Kabul, Afghanistan
>  TSE = Astana, Kazakhstan
>  KTM = Kathmandu, Nepal
>  URC = Ürümqi, Xinjiang, China
>  XNN = Xining, Qinghai, China
>  DAC = Dhaka, Bangladesh
>  RGN = Yangon, Myanmar
>  LPF = Liupanshui, Guizhou
>  XNN = Xining, Qinghai, China
>  CGK = Jakarta, Indonesia
>  PER = Perth, Australia
>  DRW = Darwin, Australia
>  ADL = Adelaide, Australia
>  BNE = Brisbane, Australia

And with a bit of Googling and doodling, I ended up with this:

> [image]

Comment: Fantastic! This reminds me of the college puzzle challenge that recently took place in the US, if anybody did that...

Comment: I like this, but what about the second part of the message? The message apparently includes directions on where to go.

Comment: Superb decoding. :)

Comment: Excellent work! You got the main part of the message, so I'll definitely give you the tick, but I'll hold off on accepting until someone's found the second, inner, hidden message.

Comment: Just remembered you were also the one to solve the Andrew Void puzzle! Look out for the next one in the series ;-)

Comment: And here it is (a year late), if you want to have a go: http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/41963/a-mysterious-email-from-the-historical-society

Answer (score 10):

Going by the same logic as @squeamish ossifrage, the second part of the message should be

> RUN = Roland Garros airport in St. Denis in Reunion.

The whole message should read:

> Roland Garros airport now

Comment: That's one way of interpreting the second message ...

Comment: Or perhaps it's referring to [Coast Guard Air Station Port Angeles (`NOW`)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coast_Guard_Air_Station_Port_Angeles)?

Comment: @squeamishossifrage is correct as to what I originally intended, but on second thoughts, "Roland Garros airport now" is a better interpretation than "Roland Garros airport, Coast Guard Station Port Angeles airport" since it only has a single destination. I'll probably incorporate this idea into the next "mysterious email" question... ;-)