# Where in the world is my friend?

Tags: knowledge, geography

A friend from my Geography Club just sent me the strangest text message. He said he is out of town on some kind of secret mission. He is also paranoid about the government reading his messages, so of course he couldn't tell me where he is. He told me to meet him as soon as possible, and left the following cryptic text, saying it would lead me to his location:

**(48,31,36),(33,42),(43,41),(43,41,44),(31,36,33),(48,38,47,45).(25,18,28),(47,28),(41,39),(32,30);(38,37,44),(21,29,24).(25,20,16),(21,19),(22,4,16),(26,17).(12,8),(4,12,8),(17,2),(3,11,2),(12,8).**

He also included the following statements which I believe are clues to figuring out how to interpret the cryptic text:

**The numbers are ordinal. Time is of the essence. Study the range. Draw with the west wind.**

I need your help! Where in the world is my friend?

Comment: (48,38,47,45).(25,18,28) is it , or .

Comment: All of the punctuation marks are correct.

Comment: I have a feeling the government will decrypt this message before we do ;)

Comment: I know you leave good clues in your puzzle, but just want to make sure if we have one here. Do we have a clue hidden up there? Also do we need "knowledge" or "trivia" tag?

Comment: There isn't a clue up there per se. I thought I would give it some time and see if anyone figures anything out. It is certainly solvable as is, but requires a particular way of thinking. Not sure about what tags I should add. I'm still pretty new at this! :)

Comment: What is the correct length of time to wait before posting a clue? Also, is it okay to add tags as clues? I would like to follow the established protocol if there is one.

Comment: If its solvable without clues, its fine for now. Give some time. Not many have seen it yet :)

Comment: Sounds good. Thanks for your help! Any advice or suggestions is always appreciated :)

Comment: See also [What is the appropriate time between hints?](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/2928/5373) And yes, adding a new tag is a perfectly acceptable form of hint.

Comment: @randal'thor Thanks so much for the info! I edited the post to include clues.

Comment: @Techidiot I added two clues to the post. Was originally planning on dropping them as periodic hints, but after reading rand al'thor's post above, decided to simply edit and include the clues.

Comment: **(V,E,J),(G,P),(Q,O),(Q,O,R),(E,J,G),(V,L,U,S).(Y,R,B),(U,B),(O,M),(F,D);
(L,K,R),(U,C,X).(Y,T,P),(U,S),(V,D,P),(Z,Q).(L,H),(D,L,H),(Q,B),(C,K,B),(L,H).** If someone is interested, here's a text version with mod 26 on the numbers.

Comment: @Techidiot the numbers represent only their own ordinal values. They are cryptic, but not encrypted. The key is finding the correct way to interpret them.

Comment: Ordinal numbers relating to geography ... maybe (48,31,36) represents the 48th, 31st, 36th largest countries in the world?

Comment: I added the knowledge tag and inserted one more clue for clarity.

Comment: The trouble is, there are too many possible ways to do this. Largest countries by area or population? Then once we've got a list of countries, where to go from there? Maybe [these](http://www.worldstandards.eu/other/tlds/) are useful somehow?

Comment: I added the 'time is of the essence' clue to help narrow it down.

Comment: I apologize about all the edits! The puzzle is much better now so I appreciate all the helpful feedback. I'm still pretty new at this... :D

Comment: Nice job on this puzzle, I didn't work on it but it was well done and well clued!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Solution:

> Each number corresponds to the order in which each state became part of the US 
>  For example, Delaware is 1, Hawaii is 50.  
>  
>  Decoding the numbers gives 
>  (AZ,CA,NV),(OR,WA),(ID,MT),(ID,MT,WY),(CA,NV,OR),(AZ,CO,NM,UT). 
>  (AR,LA,TX),(NM,TX),(MT,ND),(MN,WI); (CO,NE,WY),(IL,IA,MO). 
>  (AR,MS,TN),(IL,IN),(AL,GA,TN),(MI,OH). 
>  (NC,SC),(GA,NC,SC),(OH,PA),(NJ,NY,PA),(NC,SC). 
>  
>  
>  I noticed the only 4-group was also the only 4-way state intersection, so I guessed that each group must represent an intersection point. The 2-groups mean the point on the border of the US. Connecting the dots gives the solution! 
>  
>  [image]
>  
>  Your friend is in Reno!

Comment: Nicely done! (The puzzle itself is reminiscent of a couple I've done, such as [this one](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/41963/5373).) And welcome to the site, btw :-)

Comment: Thanks! :D Been lurking around for a while, glad I found one I could finally solve xD